# MySQL connection refused when using a flag

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

So, when I try to create the connection without the flag, it works just fine.

```
$db_init_conn = mysqli_init();
$db_conn = mysqli_real_connect($db_init_conn, HOSTNAME, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD,DATABASE);
```

But when I use the flag like this.

```
$db_init_conn = mysqli_init();
$db_conn = mysqli_real_connect($db_init_conn, HOSTNAME, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD,DATABASE,$flags=MYSQLI_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE);
```

I got this

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

What did I do wrong?

**UPDATE**

It also happens when I use other flags

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init();DBPASSWORD,DATABASE); 
$db_conn = mysqli_real_connect($mysqli, HOSTNAME, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD,DATABASE, $flags=MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS);
```

Comment: Is MySQL running on the HOSTNAME?

Comment: Of course it is. That's why it is working when I did not use the flag.

Comment: not a mysqli user myself, still : are u certain you need the `$flags=foo` assignment ? seems to me the api is not 'key-value-paired' , so would receive FLAG_AS_INT for next parameter, that is port.

Comment: I am certain I need the flag. How can I use it?

Comment: Yes, I did. I got connection refused too

Comment: not sure : am not tooled to try it at the moment. maybe ``mysqli_real_connect($mysqli,HOSTNAME,DBUSERNAME,DBPASSWORD,DATABASE,,, MYSQLI_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE); `... ymmv, i never used mysqli, so have no real knowledge, but it is what the api docs suggests to me.

Comment: It gives me `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','`

Comment: I don't know why they put the flags after the ports and sockets. That seems like a bad design. Only example I found has default port set and NULL for socket, https://books.google.com/books?id=Yat0DYXpUj8C&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=MYSQLI_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE+php+set&source=bl&ots=2O-eUZRMGV&sig=ACfU3U2n-0LJ6CiGHrtd-VG83MNtEbbjfg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibsKzQuYHqAhV5TDABHYhxBYQQ6AEwBXoECB0QAQ#v=onepage&q=MYSQLI_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE%20php%20set&f=false. (might be time to consider PDO, flags are in a logical position there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, quick installed mysqli on my box, and this gave me no errors

```
    $db_init_con = mysqli_init();
    mysqli_real_connect($db_init_con , "127.0.0.1" , "***REDACTED***" , "***REDACTED***" , "notifications" , 3306 ,null , MYSQLI_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE);
```

with mysql 5.7, php 7.2.6, osx